# Parsing a ZonedDateTime around the Daylight saving transition fails

Tags: java, date, datetime-parsing, zoneddatetime

I was testing the edge cases for my code and I ran into an unexpected effect with regards to parsing a ZonedDateTime in Java.

This parsing does not behave as I expect it in the Daylight savings transition from `Summertime` to `Wintertime`. This is the period where the clock moves back and in Europe this means that the LocalDateTime for that day has the 02:00-02:59 period twice.

Assume it is 02:30 that day then the distinction between the two local time occurrences of that time is the timezone: one is according to the "Summer time" and one is according to the "Winter time". The difference between these two Instants should be 1 hour.

So I parse these two distinct instances and then format them again to a String using the same `DateTimeFormatter`.

```java
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z");
System.out.println(fmt.format(ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-10-31 02:30:00.000 CET", fmt)));
System.out.println(fmt.format(ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-10-31 02:30:00.000 CEST", fmt)));
```

I expected to get the two input strings back but I get this instead:

```
2021-10-31 02:30:00.000 CEST
2021-10-31 02:30:00.000 CEST
```

So both are mapped to the same instant, which to me seems incorrect; they should be 1 hour apart.

To check I have done the same for the New York timezone and this gives the exact same effect:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z");
System.out.println(fmt.format(ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-11-07 01:30:00.000 EDT", fmt)));
System.out.println(fmt.format(ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-11-07 01:30:00.000 EST", fmt)));
```

gives

```
2021-11-07 01:30:00.000 EDT
2021-11-07 01:30:00.000 EDT
```

I have tried this on OpenJDK Java 1.8.0_292, 11.0.11 and 17.0.1 and all give the same output.

What am I doing wrong? What do I misunderstand?
Or have I stumbled upon a bug in Java?

---

Additional:

I ran into this problem when looping over epoch values and testing this round trip.

```java
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1635643800000L);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"));

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z");
String instantString =  fmt.format(zonedDateTime);

System.out.println(instantString);      // --> "2021-10-31 02:30:00.000 CET"
ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(instantString, fmt);
System.out.println(fmt.format(parsed)); // --> "2021-10-31 02:30:00.000 CEST"
System.out.println(parsed.toInstant().toEpochMilli()); // --> 1635640200000 != 1635643800000
```

---

Te bug report I submitted was accepted and can be found here:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8277049

Comment: My expectations agree with yours. So I’d call it a bug (if it can be reproduced).

Comment: From the docs of pattern letter `z`: *If the pattern letter is 'z' the output is the daylight savings aware zone name.* So that should mean that parsing should also include information about summer time (DST).

Comment: I found [an issue on the JDK tracker which corresponds to this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8177819), which led me to [a Stack Overflow question that I've marked this as a duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102957/datetimeformatter-parsing-timezone-names-and-daylight-savings-overlap-times). I was going to post an answer to your question, but I've posted it there instead to keep everything together. Somebody already posted a workaround on that question, which may be of interest to you. Otherwise, yes, seems like a bug.

Comment: By the way… You are using pseudo time zones, such as CET, CEST, EDT. These are not standardized; these are not even unique! [Real time zones](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) have a name in format of `Continent/Region` such as `America/New_York` and `America/Edmonton`. I suggest using ISO 8601 formats only, or the extension to that standard used by the Java class `ZonedDateTime#toString` where the time zone name is appended in square brackets.

Comment: @Michael I saw your comment too late. I've already reported this as a bug . I do find it remarkable that the one you mentioned is classified as an "Enhancement" where this to me is a bug.

Comment: @BasilBourque: I disagree with you on this one. These are the values produced by Java when you specify the 'z' format which has been defined as being a "daylight savings aware zone name" so if a round trip like this fails I think it is a bug.

Comment: @NielsBasjes I’m not referring to the bug/enhancement at all. I am saying localized text is a poor choice for data exchange. The ISO 8601 standard was written for precisely this purpose, data exchange without ambiguity. Using ISO 8691 formats makes moot the bug/enhancement issue. Those pseudo-zones should only be used when generating display text for users (if at all), not for data-exchange.

Comment: @NielsBasjes As a practical example of what Basil is getting at, BST can mean both Bangladesh Standard Time and British Summer Time. In your specific case, there is no current ambiguity for those 2 specific values, but since these identifiers are not part of any standard, you can't guarantee there won't be some other CET in the future e.g. a "Central Egypt Time". That's why either an explicit offset (e.g. "+01:00") or plain UTC is preferable.

Comment: Did you notice that @BasilBourque said *localized*? Yes, that’s right, what pattern letter `z` produces and expects for a given time zone is *dependent on locale*. Even without the bug (as I think it is) there’s a pretty huge room for confusion and errors.

Comment: Great that you have submitted a bug report! Thanks for doing that.

Comment: [Here’s my workaround](https://ideone.com/fu19Oj).

Comment: As mentioned under the linked original [there was a submitted bug already](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8177819), so yours risks being closed as a duplicate. Still I can’t see any harm done in reminding them.

Comment: Yes, there is the other report. That one is labeled as an enhancement, my report is labeled as a bug. I hope that makes a difference.